# antlr visitor is returning an empty parse tree

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, lexer

so I'm trying to print the lexemes that are being visited during lexical analysis phase, here's the code of the method that is doing so:

```
public void parse(String inputFile) {
    InputStream is = System.in;
    if (inputFile != null)
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
            PARVALexer lexer = new PARVALexer(input);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            PARVAParser parser = new PARVAParser(tokens);

            ParseTree tree = parser.prog(); // parse


            PARVAnalyzer visitor = new PARVAnalyzer();

            visitor.visit(tree);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

if I print **tokens** , I get a correct output of all the recognized lexemes in the input file, but if I print **tree** , the output is simply **[ ]**, and so the method **visit(tree)** isn't doing anything...
what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your parser couldn't match anything in the input. ANTLR parsers don't try to process the entire input unless your grammar rules force them (say if you have EOF in your rules.) Check stderr for parser messages, or try to run your input through grun to see what your parser sees. Keep in mind that if your grammar rules allow empty input then it's correct outcome, say if your start rule says something like

```
file : (record)*;
```

then an empty parse tree is a syntactically correct result when no `record` can be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem. The misunderstanding is:

> but if I print tree , the output is simply [ ]

Yes, and this is expected. Do not look at the result but execute

```
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

to proof it was correctly parsed.
I just spent one hour because I tried to locate the problem inside Antlr4 instead of noticing I used the generated BaseListener in the walker instead of my listener that had all the print statements. The tree was just fine.